# Layer blending settings that turns greyscale value into transparency (subtracting lower layers)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, transparency, blend-modes

I have a photoshop file with many layers. 
I would like to put one layer on top where I can draw transparency, so that full white (or black) is rendered as 100% alpha, so it subtracts all the layers underneath.
Is there a combination of blending modes, opacity settings, mask settings that can achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll need to do is place all of your layers into a single layer group.

From there you can add a layer mask to the actual layer group or you can place a clipping mask on the layer group.

To add the layer mask simply click *Add Layer Mask* at the bottom of the *Layer* panel.

The clipping mask is a layer that is placed above the layer group and is converted to a clipping mask by right-clicking it and selecting *Create Clipping Mask* (only available in CS6 and above for layer groups).